# convert from List<value> to IEqualityComparer<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have `Dictionary<string, List<Value>> FormControllerNamesValues` property
in my POCO object this Dictionary will have all drop down controller name and  options list for drop down controller name. my problem I can't I have this compile error

> Error 4   Argument 3: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Value>' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>'

just I want to ask how can i fix this error

```
List<Value> dropDownListrValue =
    (from val in db.Values
     where val.ParentId == (from va in db.Values
                            where va.ParentId == (from value3 in db.Values
                                                  where value3.Name == formType
                                                  select value3.RecordId).FirstOrDefault()
                            select va.RecordId).FirstOrDefault()
    select val).ToList();
result = (from value1 in db.Values
          where value1.Name == formType
          select
              new ItemManagement
              {
                  FormType = value1.Name,
                  RecordID = value1.RecordId,     
                  FormControllerNames = 
                      (from va in db.Values 
                       where va.ParentId == (from value3 in db.Values where value3.Name ==formType select value3.RecordId).FirstOrDefault()
                       select va).ToDictionary(va => va.Name, dropDownListrValue)
              }).ToList();
```

Here is my `ItemManagement` class:

```
public class ItemManagement
{
    public long RecordID { get; set; }
    public String FormType { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<Value>> FormControllerNamesValues { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: your making a dictionary with different keys but the same list for every value?

Comment: the key is different and also value

Comment: `ToDictionary(va => va.Name, dropDownListrValue)` the value is always `dropDownListrValue` for any `va.Name`, assuming that this line was supposed to look this way: `ToDictionary(va => va.Name, va => dropDownListrValue)`

Comment: yes that what I'm doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the `.ToDictionary(va => va.Name, dropDownListrValue)` method call that contains invalid arguments. The compiler resolves this call to the

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TSource> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

[overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548554(v=vs.110).aspx), and since the `dropDownListrValue` doesn't implement the `IEqualityComparer` interface, it throws the compile error.

You can change the call to `.ToDictionary(va => va.Name, va => dropDownListrValue)` to fix the compile error. This method call will resolve to the

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector
)
```

[overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.110).aspx), and return a dictionary that will contain `dropDownListrValue` value for every `va.Name` key, assuming that's what you wanted to achieve.